# “Unable to run test .. Unexpected end-of-input” on Business Rules service on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, business-rules

When testing my rules on the Business Rules service on Bluemix, I get the following error:

> "Unable to run test Error when extracting the ruleset parameter value
>   from the request. Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for
>   OBJECT (from [Source:
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTInputStream@1d255d3f; line: 1, column:
>   0]) at [Source: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTInputStream@1d255d3f;
>   line: 8, column: 123]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had misconstructed the input parameter (it was missing the closing brace):

```
{
    "foo": {
        "name": "foo",
        "id": "bar"
    }
```

Once I added the closing brace I could run the test successfully.